# How do I determine if a DBGrid is in insert mode

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I want to display another control only if a DBGrid is in insert mode. How can I detect if DBGrid or the connected DBNavigator or TQuery is in insert mode?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You check to see what `State` the underlying (connected) `TDataSet` is in ([`TDataSet.State`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.State)), using [`TDataSource.State`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Data.DB.TDataSource.State).

```
if DBGrid1.DataSource.State = dsInsert then   // It's in insert mode
```

There's also `dsEdit` to tell you if it's being edited, `dsBrowse` to let you know the `DataSet` is just being viewed, and some others.